# Looking for oldest user in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "first": "Paige",
      "last": "Bools"
    },
    "birthDate": "1995-02-04T07:34:45Z",
    "contact": {
      "phone": "8989068955",
      "email": "pbools0@webmd.com"
    },
    "address": {
      "street": "476 Veith Parkway",
      "city": "Cuamba",
      "country": "Mozambique"
    },
    "accessCount": 776,
    "isManager": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": {
      "first": "Elle",
      "last": "Bellord"
    },
    "birthDate": "2011-10-20T22:55:21Z",
    "contact": {
      "phone": "3147118248",
      "email": "ebellord1@blinklist.com"
    },
    "address": {
      "street": "31 Bay Plaza",
      "city": "Krasne",
      "country": "Ukraine"
    },
    "accessCount": 491,
    "isManager": true
  },
```

this is the file I'm using. There are like 100 of them.

/*******************************************************************************

- Problem 3: create userUtils.getOldestUser()
- 
- Add a new method to the `userUtils` Object called `getOldestUser`. This
- method will find the oldest user in the users Array and return his or her
- user Object.
- 
- In your solution, make use of the following:
- 
- - use the .forEach() method of the users Array
- - convert each user's `birthDate` from a String to a Date Object
- - use the getAgeInYears() function below to calculate the user's age
- - keep track of the largest age you see, and the user who it belongs to
- - return the full user object of the oldest user
    ******************************************************************************/

// Given a birthDate (a Date object), return an age in years.

```
function getAgeInYears(birthDate) {
  let today = new Date();
  let age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  let month = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}

userUtils.getOldestUser = function() 
{
  var oldestAge = 0;
  var oldest = users[0];
  users.forEach(x => {
    let dob = new Date(x.birthDate);
    let age = getAgeInYears(dob);
    if(age>oldestAge)
    {
      oldestAge = age;
      oldest = x;
    }

  });
  return x;
};
```

This is my code. I am making `function getAgeInYears(birthDate)` but it keeps giving me the error on `oldest` and `x`. error on x says `x` is not defined.

Comment: `return oldest;` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

**X** only exists inside the forEach function. I think what you wanted to return instead was **oldest**

Answer (score 1):

Simply return `oldest` instead of `x`.

```
userUtils.getOldestUser = function() 
{
  var oldestAge = 0;
  var oldest = users[0];
  users.forEach(x => {
    let dob = new Date(x.birthDate);
    let age = getAgeInYears(dob);
    if(age>oldestAge)
    {
      oldestAge = age;
      oldest = x;
    }

  });
  return oldest;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is caused by the fact that you do not understand parameter scope.

```
users.forEach(x => {
    //...
});
```

is a call of forEach and passing an arrow function to it. The

```
x => {
    //...
}
```

Is a shorthand of

```
(x) => {
    //...
}
```

The parantheses here is the place where you define the parameter of the function and the parameter is only known inside the function, because, outside the function you intend to be able to call the function with virtually any parameter. So, outside the function the value of the parameter is a superposition, basically it can be anything and is defined when it's called. Therefore it can only be referred to inside the function. This function will be called by `forEach`, each time passing a user to it. Inside this arrow function `oldest` is the variable which holds the oldest user found so far. At the end of the loop it will hold the oldest user. Since `oldest` is function scoped, because it's a `var`, it's scope is the scope of the function inside which it was created, which is `getOldestUser` in this case. So it makes sense to return `oldest` instead of `x`.